# Tkinker window not responding when clicked on the "Exit"

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I created a GUI using Python, Tkinter. Everything seems to be fine. I have added several options to my Menu tab. In the File section I have added a feature to exit the GUI by clickinh onto the Exit button(not the button though, but a menu option). Here is the code that I have written.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, RIGHT

class Filedialog:
    def directory(self):
        content = filedialog.askdirectory()
        return content



class Main(Frame):


    def __init__(self):
        self.opening_times = 0
        self.current_image = 0
        self.images = []
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Y")
        self.root.configure(bg='pale turquoise')
        self.root.geometry("800x800")
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.frame = Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def widgets(self):

        self.menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=self.menu)
        self.filemenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        #self.editmenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        #self.menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=self.editmenu)
        #self.editmenu.add_command(label="Undo")
        #self.editmenu.add_command(label="Redo")


    def onExit(self):
        self.root.quit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

I have almost succeeded. But the problem arises when I click on the exit. The function does what it has to. But the GUI window was **not closing, also it freezes there**. There was no response at all until I force the window to close externally.

I also tried doing:

```
self.quit()
```

/

```
self.exit()
```

But the response is the same as the GUI freezes and not letting me do any other activities. I had to close complete program to get the access again.

I am not getting the error at least, to know what is wrong.

Please help me find out what is wrong/solve this problem.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `destroy()` method instead of `quit`.

Comment: To the extend, I am doing it using Geany programming tool which is in Raspberry pi. 

When I run a program, It did open a command window along with the GUI window. When I use destroy the GUI window is closing perfectly (Thanks to @Kendoka), But is there a possibility I can close the command window(looks like terminal, all the print values are visible there) as well?

Comment: As @Faran2007 showed in his answer you can use "exit".

Comment: It's more of a problem with that you use Geany. Python is designed to run as script. "Fancy hack" you could do is killing terminal process from within python script at the end but no idea if it will work in case of Geany. Why would you even want to kill your terminal window?

Comment: Thanks man, I tried destroy yesterday but I haven't kept root before it. It is more like, a fellow using the GUI and after all the work he has done certainly to close the window.

Answer (score 3):

Let me correct your code

```
from sys import exit
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, RIGHT

class Filedialog:
    def directory(self):
        content = filedialog.askdirectory()
        return content



class Main(Frame):


    def __init__(self):
        self.opening_times = 0
        self.current_image = 0
        self.images = []
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Y")
        self.root.configure(bg='pale turquoise')
        self.root.geometry("800x800")
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.frame = Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def widgets(self):

        self.menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=self.menu)
        self.filemenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        #self.editmenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        #self.menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=self.editmenu)
        #self.editmenu.add_command(label="Undo")
        #self.editmenu.add_command(label="Redo")


    def onExit(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        exit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

You need to use `destroy()` instead of `quit()` and you should use `exit` to quit from the console

Comment: Thanks, Destroy did work. But what does the exit() do at the end?

Comment: the exit() will close the command prompt (python) because you don't need them

Comment: Thanks man, Using Spyder it did work. But the terminal window when I am using (Raspberry pi) linux it didn't work.

Comment: it's because you ran the program inside the Linux terminal :D

Comment: Alrighty. Anyhow, it did help me know more. Even though it is a small issue, thanks for helping me out. I try not to run inside the terminal :P
-peace

Comment: peace upon you too :D

Answer (score 3):

The method you have to use is `destroy`. For example:

```py
def onExit(self):
    self.root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `tk.destroy()` to close a window. The built-in functions `exit()` and `quit()` close the Python *console*.

Working example

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Closing window demonstration")

def close_window():
    tk.destroy()

quit = Button(tk, text = "Quit", command = close_window)
quit.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```